# How to add a hyperlink in asp:ListBox ListItem from Backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am showing the files of directory in listitem,i want these list items to have   download link .How can i do this ?
here is my code

```
string downloadlink;           

            foreach (FileInfo fileItem in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                downloadlink = "<a target='_blank' href='" + fileItem.DirectoryName + "'>" + fileItem.Name + "</a>";
                lstFiles.Items.Add(downloadlink);

            }
```

It is printing the download link as it is written :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where ever you want to add this control just simply add

```
HyperLink hpk = new HyperLink();
hpk.ID="hpk1";
hpk.Text="nameof the control";
hpk.NavigationURL="http://.....";
ControlName.Controls.Add(hpk);
```

Comment: i tried this but lstFiles.Controls.Add(hpk); is not working .Listbox got empty by using this :(